# Select option does not show data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, data-binding

This is my first attempt to databind an html control via ajax. I check/debug my ajax call and the data are retrieved OK, but the do not appear in the select option. My javascript is located at the bottom of my aspx page. What's the problem

```
  $(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "psHlp.asmx/getDistricts",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (msg) {
                   $("#District").empty();

                   $.each(msg.d, function () {
                       $("#District").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                   });


               },
               error: function () {
                   alert("Failed to load districts");
               }
           });
       });
```

This is my select option which is located at the beginning of my page

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 ffield">
                                        <select id="District" style="display: none;">

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. All the above suggestions were correct. The problem occurred because I'm using bootstarp js/css (customer's designer provided the layout), so I need to rebuild the multiselect option after the append.

```
 var options = "";
    $.each(response.d, function () {

        options += '<option value="' + this['Value'] + '">' + this['Text'] + '</option>';
    });
    $("#Town").append().html(options);

    $("#Town").multiselect('rebuild');
```

Hope this will help at least one person :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `(index,value)` params in your `$.each` callback function and use `value` to access the iterated elements. Something like this.

```
$.each(msg.d, function (index,value) {
    $("#District").append("<option value='" + value.Value + "'>" + value.Text + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: thank, but it did not work. I add an alert function in the loop displaying value['value'] and show correctly all the rows. What's happening??????

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle or give me the complete url to the ajax call? `"psHlp.asmx/getDistricts"`

Comment: it's not a public webservice. It's part of my local .net appliaction

Comment: What is the output you are seeing when you do a `console.log(value)` inside the `$.each()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this on your each loop.

```
var options;
$.each(msg.d, function () {
 options +=  '<option value="' + this["Value"] + '">' + this["Text"] + '</option>';
});
console.log(options);
$("#District").append(options);
```

Comment: Yes @phreakv6 is also correct, you can pass the argument in the function in the above code, and using value you can do load the value.

Comment: I've also try your suggestion but values are not populated in the select option. This the log message <option value="1">xxx</option><option value="3">zzzz</option><option value="4">ddd</option><option value="5">vvvvl</option><option value="6">mmm</option>. As you can see values are populated but the do not appear on the select option. Something prevents it from binding

Comment: @Maria h, So your getting the proper HTML Structure in your loop. So try once using like this ' $("select#District").html(options); '. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: it's still not working. I decided to make my select option as server control and bind it in the "old fashion way". Hopefully next time I attempt to use ajax it will have happy end